# Android resource linking failed when using layout_gravity="bottom||end" xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, floating-action-button, androidx

I tried to put my `FAB` on the `Bottom` right side of the screen. But every time I `build` the `app`, it always fail with `AAPT` `error` if I'm using the `android:layout_gravity="bottom||end"`

Here is the detailed error:
Android resource linking failed

> AAPT: error: 'bottom||end' is incompatible with attribute layout_gravity (attr) flags [bottom=80, center=17, center_horizontal=1, center_vertical=16, clip_horizontal=8, clip_vertical=128, end=8388613, fill=119, fill_horizontal=7, fill_vertical=112, left=3, right=5, start=8388611, top=48].

And I've tried to use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` and it works just fine.

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom||end"
```